# How to Generate Random Image from the Drawable Resource Folder with Notification or Pending Intent?

Tags: android

I am making an offline daily image quote app.
How to implement random image from Notification after they clicked it? The location of the images are stored in the drawable resource folder. Any input will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Drawable resource are `Integers` so you can create a list of ints and run a Random choose on it:

```
List<Integer> imgList = Arrays.asList(R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3, R.drawable.img4); // add your images names

Random rand = new Random();

int pickedImg = rand.nextInt(imgList.size()); // picking random number between 0 to list size - 1

ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.your_image);
imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), imgList.get(pickedImg)));
```

Comment: Okay. but what about about the Notification? How to implement Notification + Random Image?

Comment: ypu have full and easy explanation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: I want it offline so I the images are in the drawable resource folder.

Comment: the code I wrote you does work offline. it takesthe photos from the drawable resource folder